# How to run .apk file After successfull installation of it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have built an android project by eclipse

After I successfully installed my .apk file by command promot and   success word was getted 
I copied it  into a mobile in order  to run it but I getted the error

**error in parsing package**

Can someone help me thankfully.

My installation way is as follow

```
C:\Program  Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb -s emulator-5554 install -r    
 path myfile.apk
71 KB/s (533069 bytes in 7.262s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/myfile.apk
Success



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.elhadi.azkarElmuslim"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:label="أذكار "
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.elhadi.azkar.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name=".Activity1"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity3"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity4"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity5"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity6"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity7"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity9"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity10"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity11"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity12"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity13"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity14"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity15"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity16"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity17"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity18"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity19"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity20"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity21"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity22"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity23"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity24"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity25"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity26"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Activity27"></activity>
           <activity android:name=".Activity30"></activity>
             <activity android:name=".Activity31"></activity>
             <activity android:name=".Activity32"></activity>
               <activity android:name=".Activity33"></activity>
                 <activity android:name=".Activity34"></activity>
                   <activity android:name=".Activity35"></activity>
                     <activity android:name=".Activity36"></activity>
                 <activity android:name=".Activity37"></activity>
                   <activity android:name=".Activity38"></activity>


                       <activity android:name=".Activity39"></activity>
                         <activity android:name=".Activity40"></activity>
                           <activity android:name=".Activity41"></activity>
                             <activity android:name=".Activity42"></activity>
                               <activity android:name=".Activity43"></activity>
                                 <activity android:name=".Activity44"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity45"></activity>
                    <activity android:name=".Activity46"></activity>
                      <activity android:name=".Activity47"></activity> 
                        <activity android:name=".Activity48"></activity>
                          <activity android:name=".Activity49"></activity>
                            <activity android:name=".Activity50"></activity>
                              <activity android:name=".Activity51"></activity>
                                <activity android:name=".Activity52"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity53"></activity>   
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity54"></activity> 
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity55"></activity> 
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity56"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity102"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity103"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity104"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity105"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity106"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity107"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity108"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity109"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity110"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity111"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity112"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity113"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity114"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity115"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity116"></activity>
                                  <activity android:name=".Activity117"></activity>


                                   <activity android:name=".Activity118"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity119"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity120"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity121"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity122"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity123"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity124"></activity>
                                   <activity android:name=".Activity125"></activity>
                                    <activity android:name=".Activity126"></activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: It should create an icon on your list of apps. Just click it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. May be this will be reason. Please add this to support in your version. For eg: You might

written in android 4 and runs in below version in your device.So use this in manifest.

uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"

In this targetSdkVersion is what you are choosing the maximum android version to support. And

in your project, you have used 17. Try to use minsdkVersion to 8 that support from android 2.2

to above version.

Comment: Dear Helios   please in which section in my manifest  I should write what you have said?

Comment: @Elhadi Mamoun: ie in android manifest.xml file, in between application and manifest tag you can use.

Comment: Hi.You have used both as 17. so you are facing the problem. Try to reduce min sdk version to 8 ie support from android 2.2

Comment: Thank you I will try and tell  you the result

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun: surely you will get the output. Happy coding.:)

Comment: Dear Helios I have a couple of question here                        1\should  I create new emulator of android 2.2 or just change  my manifest file.                                                      2\should I copy the same .apk file in the path to the mobile                                                               thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to test in android 2.2 emulator, create an emulator and test it. If you want to test in android mobile, run it and then copy the apk from bin to mobile device.

Comment: If you given in manifest.xml, it denotes that it will support from minimum to maximum range. If you have emulator say android 4.0, you can run it. And if your mobile device is 2.3, copy the apk path and install it because you have predefined in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You just Check Your Emulator You will find the a app icon (the  icon of application you installed )just click on it it will run the application